# How to test/simulate concurrent connections for a website?

Tags: testing, connection, traffic

I would like test access time for my website (or certain page, or query) when there are 5000 concurrent connections. I want to test it for a high traffic website.

Is it possible to simulate 5000 concurrent connections? If not, how do people test such situations?

Answer (score 7):

We used [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) for this before. This tool also gives you some metrics like throughput. There is a website [here](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php) which has a bunch of open source performance tools listed, most of them related to web performance testing.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I've found a service that allows to test:

- up to 10.000 cc/sec for free.
- up to 100.000 cc/sec for 100$/month.

https://loader.io/

Disclaimer: I have nothing with this service. I post it here, maybe it helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few load testing packages out there.  HP has a tool call [LoadRunner](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-126-17%5E8_4000_100), if you click on the datasheet, it has more information.  There also is an open source tool call [OpenSTA](http://www.opensta.org/).  I just found that with a google search, so I can't tell you much about how that one works.

Answer (score 4):

You could use something like jmeter. We use this for lead testing. It allows you to simulate all sorts of user activity as test cases, run concurrent connections, submit forms, even logged in actions.

The learning curve can be steep if what you need to do is complicated, but that's because it's so feature rich!